# Make a sidebar with css

Tags: css

How can I make a sidebar with this HTML element ordering and pure CSS like attached image?

html:

```
 <div id="main">
       <div id="One"></div>
       <div id="Two"></div>
       <div id="Three"></div>
    </div>
```

desired view:

[image]

But it's like this:

[image]

I do anything by `float` & `clear` & `display` property but not working. #One, #Two and #Three has a same parent (they are sibling) and I don't wanna use absolute or fixed position.

Comment: You can try this for side navigation and keep other contents inside the `#main`  http://www.themeswild.com/read/slide-navigation-left-to-right

Comment: @SharavnanKv Thanks, but exactly these 3 div are used in my code with this ordering.

Comment: I posted the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend adding something like this to your default css file:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

.row:before,
.row:after,
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after,
.container:before,
.container:after,
.container-fluid:before,
.container-fluid:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.row:after,
.clearfix:after,
.container:after,
.container-fluid:after {
  clear: both;
}

.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 750px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}

.container-fluid {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

[class*="col-"] {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  min-height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
}

.col-xs-12 {width: 100%;}
.col-xs-11 {width: 91.66666667%;}
.col-xs-10 {width: 83.33333333%;}
.col-xs-9 {width: 75%;}
.col-xs-8 {width: 66.66666667%;}
.col-xs-7 {width: 58.33333333%;}
.col-xs-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-xs-5 {width: 41.66666667%;}
.col-xs-4 {width: 33.33333333%;}
.col-xs-3 {width: 25%;}
.col-xs-2 {width: 16.66666667%;}
.col-xs-1 {width: 8.33333333%;}
.col-xs-offset-12 {margin-left: 100%;}
.col-xs-offset-11 {margin-left: 91.66666667%;}
.col-xs-offset-10 {margin-left: 83.33333333%;}
.col-xs-offset-9 {margin-left: 75%;}
.col-xs-offset-8 {margin-left: 66.66666667%;}
.col-xs-offset-7 {margin-left: 58.33333333%;}
.col-xs-offset-6 {margin-left: 50%;}
.col-xs-offset-5 {margin-left: 41.66666667%;}
.col-xs-offset-4 {margin-left: 33.33333333%;}
.col-xs-offset-3 {margin-left: 25%;}
.col-xs-offset-2 {margin-left: 16.66666667%;}
.col-xs-offset-1 {margin-left: 8.33333333%;}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-sm-12 {width: 100%;}
  .col-sm-11 {width: 91.66666667%;}
  .col-sm-10 {width: 83.33333333%;}
  .col-sm-9 {width: 75%;}
  .col-sm-8 {width: 66.66666667%;}
  .col-sm-7 {width: 58.33333333%;}
  .col-sm-6 {width: 50%;}
  .col-sm-5 {width: 41.66666667%;}
  .col-sm-4 {width: 33.33333333%;}
  .col-sm-3 {width: 25%;}
  .col-sm-2 {width: 16.66666667%;}
  .col-sm-1 {width: 8.33333333%;}
  .col-sm-offset-12 {margin-left: 100%;}
  .col-sm-offset-11 {margin-left: 91.66666667%;}
  .col-sm-offset-10 {margin-left: 83.33333333%;}
  .col-sm-offset-9 {margin-left: 75%;}
  .col-sm-offset-8 {margin-left: 66.66666667%;}
  .col-sm-offset-7 {margin-left: 58.33333333%;}
  .col-sm-offset-6 {margin-left: 50%;}
  .col-sm-offset-5 {margin-left: 41.66666667%;}
  .col-sm-offset-4 {margin-left: 33.33333333%;}
  .col-sm-offset-3 {margin-left: 25%;}
  .col-sm-offset-2 {margin-left: 16.66666667%;}
  .col-sm-offset-1 {margin-left: 8.33333333%;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-md-12 {width: 100%;}
  .col-md-11 {width: 91.66666667%;}
  .col-md-10 {width: 83.33333333%;}
  .col-md-9 {width: 75%;}
  .col-md-8 {width: 66.66666667%;}
  .col-md-7 {width: 58.33333333%;}
  .col-md-6 {width: 50%;}
  .col-md-5 {width: 41.66666667%;}
  .col-md-4 {width: 33.33333333%;}
  .col-md-3 {width: 25%;}
  .col-md-2 {width: 16.66666667%;}
  .col-md-1 {width: 8.33333333%;}
  .col-md-offset-12 {margin-left: 100%;}
  .col-md-offset-11 {margin-left: 91.66666667%;}
  .col-md-offset-10 {margin-left: 83.33333333%;}
  .col-md-offset-9 {margin-left: 75%;}
  .col-md-offset-8 {margin-left: 66.66666667%;}
  .col-md-offset-7 {margin-left: 58.33333333%;}
  .col-md-offset-6 {margin-left: 50%;}
  .col-md-offset-5 {margin-left: 41.66666667%;}
  .col-md-offset-4 {margin-left: 33.33333333%;}
  .col-md-offset-3 {margin-left: 25%;}
  .col-md-offset-2 {margin-left: 16.66666667%;}
  .col-md-offset-1 {margin-left: 8.33333333%;}
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .col-lg-12 {width: 100%;}
  .col-lg-11 {width: 91.66666667%;}
  .col-lg-10 {width: 83.33333333%;}
  .col-lg-9 {width: 75%;}
  .col-lg-8 {width: 66.66666667%;}
  .col-lg-7 {width: 58.33333333%;}
  .col-lg-6 {width: 50%;}
  .col-lg-5 {width: 41.66666667%;}
  .col-lg-4 {width: 33.33333333%;}
  .col-lg-3 {width: 25%;}
  .col-lg-2 {width: 16.66666667%;}
  .col-lg-1 {width: 8.33333333%;}
  .col-lg-offset-12 {margin-left: 100%;}
  .col-lg-offset-11 {margin-left: 91.66666667%;}
  .col-lg-offset-10 {margin-left: 83.33333333%;}
  .col-lg-offset-9 {margin-left: 75%;}
  .col-lg-offset-8 {margin-left: 66.66666667%;}
  .col-lg-offset-7 {margin-left: 58.33333333%;}
  .col-lg-offset-6 {margin-left: 50%;}
  .col-lg-offset-5 {margin-left: 41.66666667%;}
  .col-lg-offset-4 {margin-left: 33.33333333%;}
  .col-lg-offset-3 {margin-left: 25%;}
  .col-lg-offset-2 {margin-left: 16.66666667%;}
  .col-lg-offset-1 {margin-left: 8.33333333%;}
}
```

This sets it up so you can use a basic 12-column grid system that can be responsive to media sizes. This is how Bootstrap does it. This way you simply apply a few classes to your html to accomplish the layout you want. Something like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4" id="three"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-8" id="two"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-8" id="one"></div>
</div>
```

Then you can just add a few id specific styles:

```
 #one, #two, #three {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

#one, #two {
  height: 50vh;
}

#three {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/tbellerose/zzfya9d2/) is a jsfiddle demonstrating what I'm talking about.

Again, you don't have to use this method exactly, but I find it highly useful to use a css grid system like this. If you google css grids, you'll find a bunch of other ways.

EDIT:

Okay, if you have to maintain the div order, then you can do this.

html:

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="One">
    One
  </div>
  <div id="Two">
    Two
  </div>
  <div id="Three">
    Three
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#main:before,
#main:after {
  content:'';
  display: table;
}

#main:after {
  clear:both;
}

#One, #Two, #Three {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

#Three {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 20%
}

#One, #Two {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 80%;
  float: right;
}
```

The [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tbellerose/te7c76wt/).

And of course you can play with the height, margins, etc of #One and #Two to arrive at the aesthetic you want.

Comment: Thanks but for SEO reason I can not change div ordering, It must be #One , #Two and #Three

Answer (score 1):

Here you go
HTML:

```
<div id="main"> 
   <div id="one" class="right-side">
     <p>
     one
     </p>
   </div>
   <div id="two" class="right-side">
     <p>
     Two
     </p>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div id="three">
     <p>
     Three
     </p>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
p{
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
 padding-top:30px;
 font-size:30px;
 margin:0;
}
.right-side{
  margin-left:200px;
}
#one{
  height:48vh;
  background-color:#222;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
#two{
    height:40vh;
  background-color:#222;
}
#three{
  width:200px;
  position:fixed;
  background-color:#222;
  height:100vh;
  left:0;
  top:0;
}
```

DEMO : https://jsfiddle.net/Lt8ovoqw/2/

Comment: Thanks,but  #One, #Two and #Three should be siblings and I don't wanna use absolute or fixed position.

Comment: Is it possible to use only static position to all divs? absolute or fixed positions will not working for me.

Comment: yes you can remove `position:fixed` and make `#one` `#two` `#three` as `float:right`

Answer (score 0):

Code for the side bar  #Three and #One

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="left-sidebar">
            <ul class="sidebar-menu">
                #THREE                  
            </ul>
        </div>
       <div class="right-main-content">
           #ONE
    </div>
</div>

.wrapper {width:100%;height:100%;}
.content{padding-top:20px;}
.left-sidebar {width:120px;height:200px;margin:0 0 0 0;border:1px solid red;float:left;}
.right-main-content{margin:0 60px 0 140px;border: 1px solid green;}
.right-other-content{margin:0 60px 0 140px;border: 1px solid green; padding-top:20px;}
.sidebar-menu{list-style-type:none;}
.project-picture-bar{height:100px;width:100%;border-top:3px solid grey;border-bottom:3px solid grey;}
```

Comment: I can not use div.content in my code. #One, #Two and #Three are sibling.